# url generates invalid character constant error

Tags: rest, api, karate

Using Karate for API testing:
I tried passing url at given method

Getting invalid character constant error:
given url 'http://localhost:8080'
and header content-type = "application/json"

Comment: Team? What Team? Did you mean to post this to an internal discussion group?

Comment: this is a terrible question: please read this and try again: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple example:

```
Feature: sample karate script that calls a live www web-service

Background:
* url 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'

Scenario: test
    Given path 'users'
    When method get
    Then status 200
```